# Custom nintext workflow approval system

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

Small back-story,
This Item needs to go to get tested. In order to get it tested It needs to go through a list of approvers and get approved. There are 3 options that can be selected when the approval process is started. This list is always changing never the same size for any particular project. We have no way of telling a max number of people, or a minimum. This process needs to be quick. So our plan is to create a workflow that sends out an approval form to all people on this list, but if a single person chooses reject it needs to stop the workflow before anyone else has to waste their time reading an email and responding. I've tried running a parallel loop with a run If and stop loop inside it with no luck. Is there any way to ensure that once anyone has selected reject this is rejected immediately and not waiting for everyone else's approval? Also this is a Flexi-task because the possibility of a 3rd option (not applicable) has to be available.

The all must approve isn't an option, there's a possibility of a 3rd option called no-impact meaning that it doesn't effect the person who gets the email, but they still need to get it (not all companies keep their records up to date this customer seems to be one). Also when you use the nintex workflow approval system it waits till everyone responds till it does its next command, that's what I'm looking to stop. I need it to close the workflow IMMEDIATELY upon any one of the people on the list rejecting it.

Answer (score 0):

The Request Approval tool in Nintex workflow includes several options, including "All must approve", "Only one approval is required", "First response applies" and "Vote".  If only one disapproval is enough to not approve the process, then I would select "All must approve".

Comment: I added some more description to the question, to add clarity